# Multiple drivers conflict for unknown reason

Tags: verilog, fpga

I'm working on a 4-bit divider using subtractors. It works fine on my testbench, but when I use it in my project and do "apio build," I get the following warnings:

```
Warning: multiple conflicting drivers for top.\div.auxNumerador_next [3]:
port Q[3] of cell $flatten\div.$auto$proc_dlatch.cc:427:proc_dlatch$866 ($dlatch)
port Q[3] of cell $flatten\div.$procdff$895 ($adff)
Warning: multiple conflicting drivers for top.\div.auxNumerador_next [2]:
port Q[2] of cell $flatten\div.$auto$proc_dlatch.cc:427:proc_dlatch$866 ($dlatch)
port Q[2] of cell $flatten\div.$procdff$895 ($adff)
Warning: multiple conflicting drivers for top.\div.auxNumerador_next [1]:
port Q[1] of cell $flatten\div.$auto$proc_dlatch.cc:427:proc_dlatch$866 ($dlatch)
port Q[1] of cell $flatten\div.$procdff$895 ($adff)
Warning: multiple conflicting drivers for top.\div.auxNumerador_next [0]:
port Q[0] of cell $flatten\div.$auto$proc_dlatch.cc:427:proc_dlatch$866 ($dlatch)
port Q[0] of cell $flatten\div.$procdff$895 ($adff)
Warning: multiple conflicting drivers for top.\div.cociente_next [3]:
port Q[3] of cell $flatten\div.$auto$proc_dlatch.cc:427:proc_dlatch$822 ($dlatch)
port Q[3] of cell $flatten\div.$procdff$893 ($adff)
Warning: multiple conflicting drivers for top.\div.cociente_next [2]:
port Q[2] of cell $flatten\div.$auto$proc_dlatch.cc:427:proc_dlatch$822 ($dlatch)
port Q[2] of cell $flatten\div.$procdff$893 ($adff)
Warning: multiple conflicting drivers for top.\div.cociente_next [1]:
port Q[1] of cell $flatten\div.$auto$proc_dlatch.cc:427:proc_dlatch$822 ($dlatch)
port Q[1] of cell $flatten\div.$procdff$893 ($adff)
Warning: multiple conflicting drivers for top.\div.cociente_next [0]:
port Q[0] of cell $flatten\div.$auto$proc_dlatch.cc:427:proc_dlatch$822 ($dlatch)
port Q[0] of cell $flatten\div.$procdff$893 ($adff)
Warning: multiple conflicting drivers for top.\div.next_state [2]:
port Q[2] of cell $flatten\div.$auto$proc_dlatch.cc:427:proc_dlatch$795 ($dlatch)
port Q[2] of cell $flatten\div.$procdff$892 ($adff)
Warning: multiple conflicting drivers for top.\div.next_state [1]:
port Q[1] of cell $flatten\div.$auto$proc_dlatch.cc:427:proc_dlatch$795 ($dlatch)
port Q[1] of cell $flatten\div.$procdff$892 ($adff)
Warning: multiple conflicting drivers for top.\div.next_state [0]:
port Q[0] of cell $flatten\div.$auto$proc_dlatch.cc:427:proc_dlatch$795 ($dlatch)
port Q[0] of cell $flatten\div.$procdff$892 ($adff)
Warning: Driver-driver conflict for \div.cociente_next [3] between cell $flatten\div.$auto$proc_dlatch.cc:427:proc_dlatch$822.Q and constant 1'0 in top: Resolved using constant.
Warning: Driver-driver conflict for \div.cociente_next [2] between cell $flatten\div.$auto$proc_dlatch.cc:427:proc_dlatch$822.Q and constant 1'0 in top: Resolved using constant.
Warning: Driver-driver conflict for \div.cociente_next [1] between cell $flatten\div.$auto$proc_dlatch.cc:427:proc_dlatch$822.Q and constant 1'0 in top: Resolved using constant.
Warning: Driver-driver conflict for \div.cociente_next [0] between cell $flatten\div.$auto$proc_dlatch.cc:427:proc_dlatch$822.Q and constant 1'0 in top: Resolved using constant.
Warning: Driver-driver conflict for \div.next_state [2] between cell $flatten\div.$auto$proc_dlatch.cc:427:proc_dlatch$795.Q and constant 1'0 in top: Resolved using constant.
Warning: Driver-driver conflict for \div.next_state [1] between cell $flatten\div.$auto$proc_dlatch.cc:427:proc_dlatch$795.Q and constant 1'0 in top: Resolved using constant.
Warning: Driver-driver conflict for \div.next_state [0] between cell $flatten\div.$auto$proc_dlatch.cc:427:proc_dlatch$795.Q and constant 1'0 in top: Resolved using constant.
```

Plus, when I upload it to my FPGA, and it's time to use it, the FPGA doesn't do anything. Could you please give me some guidance on what I'm doing wrong?

Here is the code that I am using:

```
module divisor(
    input wire clk, 
    reset,
    input wire iniciar,
    input wire [3:0] numerador, 
    denominador,
    output wire [3:0] cociente, 
    resto,
    output reg terminado, 
    listo
);

localparam [2:0]
    s0 = 3'b000,
    s1 = 3'b001,
    s2 = 3'b010,
    s3 = 3'b011,
    s4 = 3'b100;

reg [2:0] state, next_state;
reg [3:0] cociente_reg, cociente_next, resto_reg, resto_next;
reg [3:0] auxNumerador_reg, auxNumerador_next;

always @(posedge clk, posedge reset) begin
    if (reset) begin
        state <= s0;
        cociente_reg <= 4'b0000;
        resto_reg <= 4'b0000;
        auxNumerador_reg <= 4'b0000;
    end else begin
        state <= next_state;
        cociente_reg <= cociente_next;
        resto_reg <= resto_next;
        auxNumerador_reg <= auxNumerador_next;
    end
end

always @* begin
    state = next_state;
    listo = 1'b0;
    terminado = 1'b0;
    cociente_reg = cociente_next;
    resto_reg = resto_next;
    auxNumerador_reg = auxNumerador_next;
    case (state)
        s0:
            begin
                listo = 1'b1;
                if(iniciar)begin
                    auxNumerador_next = numerador;
                    cociente_next = 4'b0000;
                    if (denominador == 4'b0000 || numerador == 4'b0000 )
                        next_state = s3;
                    else
                        next_state = s1;
                end 
            end
        s1:
            begin
                auxNumerador_next = auxNumerador_reg - denominador;
                cociente_next = cociente_reg + 1;
                if(auxNumerador_next < denominador) 
                    next_state = s2;
            end
        s2:
            begin
                resto_next = auxNumerador_reg;
                next_state = s4;
            end
        s3:
            begin
                resto_next = numerador;
                next_state = s4;
            end
        s4:
            begin
                terminado = 1'b1;
                next_state = s0;
            end
        default: 
            next_state = s0; 
    endcase
end

assign cociente = cociente_reg;
assign resto = resto_reg;

endmodule
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has multiple drivers of these signals:

```
state
cociente_reg
resto_reg
auxNumerador_reg
```

You are making assignments to those signals from 2 different `always` blocks.  You should not do that.  I think you want to swap the order of the "next" signals in the combinational logic block (`always @*`).

Change:

```
always @* begin
    state = next_state;
    listo = 1'b0;
    terminado = 1'b0;
    cociente_reg = cociente_next;
    resto_reg = resto_next;
    auxNumerador_reg = auxNumerador_next;
```

to:

```
always @* begin
    next_state = state;
    listo = 1'b0;
    terminado = 1'b0;
    cociente_next = cociente_reg;
    resto_next = resto_reg;
    auxNumerador_next = auxNumerador_reg;
```

That should also avoid inferring unintended latches.